# Parameter in AJAX request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view which contain multiple links:

```
<% a.each do |q| %> 
   <%= link_to "stock it", 
        { :action => "stock", 
          :qid => q.question_id, 
          :qur => q.question_answers_url, 
          :qti => q.title } , 
        :remote => true %> 

   <div id="<%= "stock" + q.question_id.to_s %>"></div>
<% end %>
```

Each link generate AJAX-request.  Here is a controller:

```
def stock
  if(!Later.where(:question_id => params[:qid]).exists?)
    later = Later.new(:question_id => params[:qid], :name => params[:qti], :url => params[:qur])
    later.save
  end 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :layout=>false }
  end
end
```

Now return to the view.  Each link has a 'div' with unique id='stock'.  When user press the link I need to add text to specific div with corresponding id.

I have a stock.js.erb file:

```
$("#stock<number>").html("some text");
```

How can I pass div-id to stock.js.erb and how can I use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common use is to add `object.id` to your DOM id. That what you exactly did:

```
<div id="<%= "stock_#{q.question_id}" %>"></div>
```

Then in your controller you shoud define your `question_id` or your exact `question`:

```
def stock
  if(!Later.where(:question_id => params[:qid]).exists?)
    later = Later.new(:question_id => params[:qid], :name => params[:qti], :url => params[:qur])
    later.save
  end
  @question_id = params[:qid]
end
```

Now it will be shared with your `stock.js.erb` file:

```
$("#stock_<%= @question_id %>").html("some text");
```

Comment: If I put $("#stock_5610929").html("some text 3"); in the stock.js.erb - it works, but $("#stock_#{@question_id}").html("some text"); doesn't.

Comment: use `<%= @question_id %>` istead of `#{...}` :)